# How to detect the change in direction(in degrees) using Android smartphone

Tags: android, arduino, rotation, accelerometer, gyroscope

What i am trying to do is detect the...."heading" of a user from the android smartphone in it's pocket. For example let's say he/she is going down a straight street. When he/she takes an x degree turn to another street i want to be able to detect those x degrees. Basically suposing there is a normal vector to the user, i need to get the rotation of that vector around it's origin, the user.

I will be even more specific. I have a device composed of an accelerometer and gyroscope module(MPU6050), a bluetooth module and 2 ultrasonic sensors connected to an Arduino Nano that sits on top the users hand and sends data(acceleration, rotation of the hand and distance to objects) to the Android device. The user has it's hand streched in front of him and moves it form left to right(like a blind person uses a white cane). 
Initially, at startup the arduino device calibrates and consideres that the direction the user is facing with it's hand straight in front is 0 degrees. As the user moves it's hand left to right the device reports the angle of the hand. Say the user moves it's hand 30 degrees to the right from the initial, straight in front position, the Arduino device will send +30 degrees to the smartphone.
The important part is tat i'm interested only in the position of the hand. If the user rotates 40 degrees to the right the angle sent to the smartphone will be 30+40=70 degrees. What i need is to mitigate that, detect the change of 40 degrees on the Android smartphone and use it to correct the angle send by the Arduino device so that if a user has it's hand at 30 degrees relative to the direction he is facing, no matter its position in the real world the Android app will report after correction 30 degrees, the position of the hand.

I tried using this: http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html but it doesn't give accurate, reliable results.

I'm sorry for the long post, i was trying to explain as detailed as possible what is the problem i try to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you can get the reading from the Android phone, and it is just that the rotation reading is not accurate enough from the phone. How about add the 3rd arduino device on the body (say on the chest) as the reference point ? This way, you just need to read the relative degree between the hand and the referecen point.

Comment: I thought about this but i don't want to and i also don't have another accelerometer&gyro module so i want to take advantage of the ones integrated on the smartphone